# Sorting Photos by Filename into Folders in Python

Tags: python, sorting, photo

I am trying to sort photos located in a folder by their name into folders of the same name.

```
project/photos_to_sort/
IMG_20200101_001.jpg
IMG_20200101_002.jpg
IMG_20200103_001.jpg
IMG_20200207_001.jpg
IMG_20200207_002.jpg
IMG_20200207_003.jpg
```

Script should create 3 folders with the names: 20200101, 20200103, 20200207 and then place the photos into the correct folders.

```
project/sorted/20200101/
IMG_20200101_001.jpg
IMG_20200101_002.jpg
project/sorted/20200103/
IMG_20200103_001.jpg
project/sorted/20200207/
IMG_20200207_001.jpg
IMG_20200207_002.jpg
IMG_20200207_003.jpg
```

Here is my code so far but I can seem to get this to work:

```
import os
import shutil


# Input absolute path to PhotoSort program.
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\PhotoSort")


for f in os.listdir("photos_to_sort"):
    folderName = f[4:12]

if os.path.exists(folderName):
    shutil.copy(
        os.path.join("C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\PhotoSort\\", f),
        os.path.join("C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\PhotoSort\\sorted\\", folderName),
    )
else:
    os.mkdir(folderName)
    shutil.copy(
        os.path.join("C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\PhotoSort\\", f),
        os.path.join("C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\PhotoSort\\sorted\\", folderName),
    )
```

This spits out a FileNotFoundError at the moment.

Comment: hey falconed! may we see the whole error, with the exact line it reffers? that way the problem can be a lot easier to spot.

Comment: use ``os.makedirs`` for creating a directory recursively, instead of ``os.makedir``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folderName is not a valid path it is just a string you have to create path as
**sorted/folderName** as you have mentioned. And also your photos are in **photos_to_sort** folder and you are using the root folder.

And when you are setting your absolute path using a relative path makes things simpler and works on other machines also.

It is best practice to create path using os.path.join as it creates path according to the underlying operating system so that your script can run both on Windows and Linux/ Unix

Below is working code

```
import os
import shutil


# Input absolute path to PhotoSort program.
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\PhotoSort")


for f in os.listdir("photos_to_sort"):
    folderName = f[4:12]

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join("sorted", folderName)):
        shutil.copy(
            os.path.join(
                "photos_to_sort", f),
            os.path.join(
                "sorted", folderName),
        )
    else:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(
            "sorted", folderName))
        shutil.copy(
            os.path.join(
                "photos_to_sort", f),
            os.path.join(
                "sorted", folderName),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `os.makedirs(folder_name, exist_ok=True)`

This will create directory only if it does not exist. Then you can use shutil copy command along with the above function in a for loop to do the job. Also, check the placement of your if condition.

```
dest_path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\PhotoSort\\sorted\\"

for f in sorted(os.listdir("photos_to_sort")):
    folderName = f[4:12]
    dest_img_folder = os.path.join(dest_path,folderName)
    os.makedirs(dest_img_folder,exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy(
        os.path.join("C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\PhotoSort\\", f),
        os.path.join(dest_img_folder,f), # also specify the absolute file path 
    )
```